# Drupal | Remove image styles for specific node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

We're building a custom tool that requires us to remove image styles (derivatives). It's very simple to remove all image styles for all nodes via drush or programatically.

How can we remove all image styles for a single node?

Comment: Can you just find image path with image_style_url() or something and delete image file?

Comment: That's what I thought. However, this only ID's the originally uploaded image, not the associated derivative sizes. We're working on writing a custom module to fit what we need. More suggestions welcome.